# Лучшее решение для лайк/дизлайк, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В приложении стоит devise и только аутентифицированные пользователи могут ставить лайки. Хочу изменить и дать эту возможность всем юзерам.

Возникает вопрос, как отслеживать голоса и не допускать повторного голоса одного и того же человека? Сейчас отслеживается просто колонкой `user_id`

Comment: У меня встречный вопрос: а разве вообще существует способ установить уникальность гостя в системе? Можно, конечно, воспользоваться вот этими вариантами https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8# , но любой из них можно обойти.

Comment: Есть у меня одна анонимная имджборда, там лойсы и дизлойсы привязываются к сессиям. Естественно, это можно обойти, если удалить куку, в которой содержится идентификатор сессии.

Comment: Самое простое: запрещать больше одного голоса в сутки с одного айпи, скажем.

Comment: https://github.com/samyk/evercookie

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете цеплять cookie к браузеру пользователя, мол он уже отмечал этот пост. Но в таком случае, удаление cookie позволит пользователю проголосовать еще раз.

Вы можете запрещать голосовать по ip, но это тоже не вариант, ибо ip легко сменить, а еще они бывает динамический.

Есть еще способы, но их все так же легко обойти... Так что, на мой взгляд, это не очень удачное решение, ибо "накрутки" голосов вам в любом случае неизбежать